# Adding extra minutes of time to Current Clock Time in MATLAB (time-zone)

Tags: matlab, loops, time, real-time, clock

I'd like to add the variable `Correction` to the current time in order to get a new time.

Here is my code to get the current time (working):

```
datestr(now);
d = rem(now,1);
datestr(d);
time = datestr(d, 'HH:MM');
```

Here is my code on showing how to get the Correction factor (working):

```
c = clock();
tsNow = datenum(c);
tsStart = datenum([c(1) 1 1 0 0 0]); 
daysInYear = tsNow - tsStart;
DayOfYear = floor(daysInYear);

B = 360/365*(DayOfYear-81);
EoT = 9.87*sind(2*B)-7.53*cosd(B)-1.5*sind(B);
Correction = EoT - (4*(0-3.173));
Declination = 23.45*sind((360/365)*(284+DayOfYear));
```

How do I parse `Correction` so that it adds its value in HH:MM format to the current time? Simply putting

```
AST = time + Correction;
```

Prints AST as a vector with 6 values.

Note: HH:MM format is 24 hour format and Correction is usually adding between 0-60 minutes to the clock time so i'm not sure how it will deal with the remainder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `time` which is of type `string` to `Correction` which is a number you won't get anything reasonable.

`datenum` can help you here. It can converts a **date vector** to **date number**. I am no expert on this issue. But I know that the data format the command `now` returns is called a **date number**. (See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/date-and-time-operations.html) for other functions and see their input and output types)

However in your case it's easier to deal with **date vector** representation of time:

> > A full date vector has six elements, specifying year, month, day, hour, minute, and second, in that order. .... Example: `[2003,10,24,12,45,07]`

So, you can convert the `Correction` time to **date number** using `datenum` and then add it to value acquired from `now` (here `d`):

`datestr(d + datenum([0 0 0 0 0 Correction]))`

This is considering `Correction` to be in seconds.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Correction is measured in minutes with the decimal part of the value representing seconds. I tried this final line of code but it didn't work with Correction in any of the last 3 positions (for minutes). In the 4th position it returns an incorrect DATE and time. Any further thoughts?

Edit: Apologies, I forgot to re-run the program so it was using the incorrect value of time from when the program was last run. I think this works. Is the new value from datestr(d + datenum...) now a string or a number?

Comment: Well if it's in minutes you should put in as the second element of the vector: `[0 0 0 0 Correction 0]`. Even if the `Correction` is not an integer, no problem, the decimal part will be added to seconds. I mean `0.1` minutes would be 6 seconds of course.

Comment: `datestr` returns a string, please take a loot at the link I put, it will help you.